# Обработка даты в запросе к базе

Tags: php, mysql

Вообщем есть запрос на вставку данных в базу. В запросе есть три даты. Формируются они так.

```
$Birthdate = $BYear.'-'.$BMonth.'-'.$BDay;
$DateOfExpire = $ExpireYear.'-'.$ExpirelMonth.'-'.$DateDay;
$DateOfIssu = $IssueYear.'-'.$IssueMonth.'-'.$IssueDay;
```

Я конечно могу переделать само формирование дат, но смысл в том что в таблицу вставляются только 2 даты.

И не важно какие. Переменные для вставки я могу менять местами - эффект будет тот же. 
Но самое интересное - если для третьей даты, задать формат поля тектовым - вставляется не полная дата, а минусованная. 
Например, переменную $DateOfExpire ставлю

```
echo $DateOfExpire;
```

Выведет 2046-11-12, а в базу добавит 2013.) Причем как я уже сказал - любые первые 2 даты - добавляет нормально. Если меняю их местами - эффект тот же.

Comment: Код вставки в студию!

Comment: @RattleSneyk, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Как формируете сами даты, с помощью чего вставляете, попробуйте распечатать сам уходящий запрос при возможности. Просто имена переменных из которых вы строите строку ни о чем не говорят(да и гадать по кофейной гуще тут не все умеют, что бы узнать нужные подробности).

Answer (score 1):

Когда вставляете дату в базу, обрамляйте ее кавычками:

INSERT INTO `table` SET `DateOfExpire`='$DateOfExpire'

Иначе mysql думает, что нужно вычислить число, а потом только записать результат вычислений.
P.s.: И зачем для хранения даты в базе использовать строковый тип? Date - уже не модно?